# Load Kernel Module during boot without /etc/modules entry

Tags: module, kernel, load

I have a custom linux kernel module, which is an SPI driver and, given that I build the kernel and FS from sources, would like to the module to load during boot like many other kernel modules do.

The module resides and builds as part of the kernel structure i.e. within input/misc, however, currently, to get my module to load, I need to add an entry to /etc/modules, then run depmod. It would be convenient to not have to do this each time a new image is flashed.

Thanks

Comment: Why not compile it into the kernel binary?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes this is an option, however, its still useful during development to have separate kernel modules. The kernel I have has a number of modules that get loaded without having an entry in /etc/modules and so I was wondering how this is so.

Comment: I guess you can have a "dev kernel config file" vs a "prod kernel config file". Also, depending on your distro, you could add an init script to load the module.